# Javascript files are not coming in lib folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to refresh part of view, so I want to use Ajax.BeginForm. Fo this I am installing jquery.unobtrusive-ajax plugin from nuget package manager.

The problem is, After installation of Package from Nuget, JavaScript files are not coming in lib or script folder.

Am I making any mistake or there is a different way to do it?

Thanks
Keval

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include JavaScript packages I install from Nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485684/how-do-i-include-javascript-packages-i-install-from-nuget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scripts use bower / npm / yarn / libman. Nuget is not recommended for client side libraries. It is for installing server side packages / libraries.

Comment: What if, I download Javascript file and keep in lib folder instead of installing via bower / npm? and then put it as reference on view.

Comment: No harm in that. But the above specified client library management tools help you to do it better. For example when you're adding the solution to source control, if you're doing manual approach you need to commit the files, but if you're using any tools, the tool manages that.